# Ferris wheel question from Checkpoint book 11-14

Tags: trigonometry, applications

The question is from checkpoint book 11-14 from section 4, chapter 19, Shape, Space and measures. Question number 8

A ferris wheel, centre O, has a diameter of 10m and carries eight equally spaced carriages for children to sit in. The carriages are numbered from 1-8.

I've query regarding a subquestion...

**(c)** the shortest distance between carriages 1 and 4.

I saw checkpoint answer sheets, answer is  9.2m.

Any help regarding above is really appreaciated.

Thanks,
Arif

Answer (score 1):

Let point $P$ denote the first carriage and point $Q$ denote the second carriage. We observe the following about the triangle $OPQ$:

- Both $OP$ and $OQ$ have length 5 (the radius of the ferris wheel).
- The angle $POQ$ has measure $3\pi / 4$ (the carriages are equally spaced and there are eight of them).

Let $c$ denote the length of the side $PQ$. Using the law of cosines,
$$
\begin{align*}
c^2 &= 5^2 + 5^2 - 2\cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot \cos(3\pi /4)\\
&= 50 + 25\sqrt{2},
\end{align*}
$$
and so $c = \sqrt{50 + 25 \sqrt{2}} \approx 9.2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  use the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).  What is the angle between carriages 1 and 4?